# Turning Mysql values row into columns by form_id and entry_id

Tags: mysql, pivot

I would like to understand how I can turn these rows into columns in MySql

This is how the DB is saved:

| id | form_id | entry_id | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 18 | Name |
| 2 | 7 | 18 | Date |
| 3 | 7 | 18 | Phone |
| 4 | 7 | 18 | Email |
| 5 | 7 | 18 | Status |
| 6 | 8 | 19 | DOB |
| 7 | 8 | 19 | Address |
| 8 | 8 | 19 | Post Code |
| 9 | 8 | 19 | Country |
| 10 | 8 | 19 | Notes |
| 11 | 7 | 20 | Name |
| 12 | 7 | 20 | Date |
| 13 | 7 | 20 | Phone |
| 14 | 7 | 20 | Email |
| 15 | 7 | 20 | Status |
| 16 | 8 | 21 | DOB |
| 17 | 8 | 21 | Address |
| 18 | 8 | 21 | Post Code |
| 19 | 8 | 21 | Country |
| 20 | 8 | 21 | Notes |

That is how the table is currently, the idea is combining both form_id (7 & 8) and as a row:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5 | column 6 | column 7 | column 8 | column 9 | column 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Date | Phone | Email | Status | DOB | Address | Post Code | Country | Notes |
| Name | Date | Phone | Email | Status | DOB | Address | Post Code | Country | Notes |

I have tried with INNER JOIN and Pivot but I am stuck all day on that. If you guys could help would be amazing.

Thanks in advanced

Here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=943eb14a4fd39476033e18eb0aa625e8

Comment: This is PIVOT. Not implemented. Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please put your table and data into a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) so that anyone who wishes to help can try out their solutions... help us to help you! It means that there is a single source of truth **and** means that there's no duplication of effort!

Comment: Is this strictly MySQL, or would you consider MariaDB as well? (Because there is a solution for this in MariaDB.)

Comment: Follow the [pivot] tag.

Comment: Hi, @Vérace many thanks for your help, here is the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=943eb14a4fd39476033e18eb0aa625e8

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: @dbdemon thanks for your comment, yes strictly Mysql. Thanks

Comment: I will be having a go again with Pivot table and let you guys know, any help will be much appreciated, thanks to all :)